# Flare Actor is not working inside Positioned Widget or even in Column or in Row in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flare

```
               children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 1,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 300,
                      width: 300,
                      child: FlareActor(
                        'assets/New File 5 (2).flr',
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        isPaused: true,
                        animation: 'Checkmark Appear',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

There is a Stack Widget name above the Children named argument. When I tried running The Flare Actor Widget inside the Column, Row, or List Widgets, it didn't work and it disappeared . But when I used it inside a Stack it worked great but I could not position it right. When I checked my debug console there is an error which appeared to me and this is it:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (18558): RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (18558): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (18558): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter (18558): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is:
I/flutter (18558):   RenderStack#2151d relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (18558):   creator: Stack ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
I/flutter (18558):   AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#874dd ink
 renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ←
I/flutter (18558):   AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← ⋯
I/flutter (18558):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
I/flutter (18558):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=560.0) size: Size(360.0, 560.0)
I/flutter (18558):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter (18558):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter (18558):   fit: loose
I/flutter (18558):   overflow: clip
I/flutter (18558): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
I/flutter (18558):   RenderStack#2151d relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (18558):   creator: Stack ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
I/flutter (18558):   AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#874dd ink
I/flutter (18558):   renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ←
I/flutter (18558):   AnimatedPhysicalModel ← Material ← ⋯
I/flutter (18558):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
I/flutter (18558):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=560.0)
I/flutter (18558):   size: Size(360.0, 560.0)
I/flutter (18558):   alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart
I/flutter (18558):   textDirection: ltr 
I/flutter (18558):   fit: loose
I/flutter (18558):   overflow: clip
I/flutter (18558): The constraints that applied to the RenderStack were:
I/flutter (18558):   BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter (18558): The exact size it was given was:
I/flutter (18558):   Size(Infinity, Infinity)
I/flutter (18558): See https://flutter.dev/layout/ for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the size issue...

Read the following error carefully

> I/flutter (18558): RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
>
> I/flutter (18558): This probably means that it is a render object that
> tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
> inside another render object that allows its
> children to pick their own size.

Focus on these lines, you will understand the issue

> **but it was put
> inside another render object that allows its
> children to pick their own size.**

Apply the following additions:

- Add position offsets in the Positioned widget.
- Increase the size of SizedBox to (360.0, 560.0).
- Replace Sizedbox() with a Container().
- Rename your flare file and reimport.
- add a fit property in FlareActor().
- Use a proper parent widget for Flareactor() that do not restrict child size.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually put it in a Expanded() and have e.g. a Container as the child. E.g. this works perfectly fine:

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FlareActor(
```

That way, you can put multiple flares in one column. There is a great documenation. Just scroll down to Example 25 here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the FlareActor with Expanded():
Example:

```
Expanded(child: FlareActor("Assets/wellness.flr", alignment:Alignment.center, fit:BoxFit.contain, animation:"idle")),
```